# Multiple entries with same key immutable map error

Tags: java, multithreading, guava, builder, builder-pattern

I have a below builder class which I am using from multithread application so I have made it thread safe. Just for simplicity, I am showing only few fields here to demonstrate the problem.

```
public final class ClientKey {
  private final long userId;
  private final int clientId;
  private final String processName;
  private final Map<String, String> parameterMap;

  private ClientKey(Builder builder) {
    this.userId = builder.userId;
    this.clientId = builder.clientId;
    this.processName = builder.processName;
    // initializing the required fields
    // and below line throws exception once I try to clone the `ClientKey` object
    builder.parameterMap.put("is_clientid", (clientId == 0) ? "false" : "true");
    this.parameterMap = builder.parameterMap.build();
  }

  public static class Builder {
    private final long userId;
    private final int clientId;
    private String processName;
    private ImmutableMap.Builder<String, String> parameterMap = ImmutableMap.builder();

    // this is for cloning
    public Builder(ClientKey key) {
      this.userId = key.userId;
      this.clientId = key.clientId;
      this.processName = key.processName;
      this.parameterMap =
          ImmutableMap.<String, String>builder().putAll(key.parameterMap);
    }

    public Builder(long userId, int clientId) {
      this.userId = userId;
      this.clientId = clientId;
    }

    public Builder parameterMap(Map<String, String> parameterMap) {
      this.parameterMap.putAll(parameterMap);
      return this;
    }

    public Builder processName(String processName) {
      this.processName = processName;
      return this;
    }

    public ClientKey build() {
      return new ClientKey(this);
    }
  }

  // getters
}
```

Below is how I make `ClientKey` and it works fine.

```
Map<String, String> testMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
testMap.put("hello", "world");
ClientKey keys = new ClientKey.Builder(12345L, 200).parameterMap(testMap).build();
```

Now when I try to clone the `keys` object as shown below, it throws exception.

```
ClientKey clonedKey = new ClientKey.Builder(keys).processName("hello").build();
```

It throws exception with error message as: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Multiple entries with same key: is_clientid=true and is_clientid=true`

```
builder.parameterMap.put("is_clientid", (clientId == 0) ? "false" : "true");
// from below line exception is coming
this.parameterMap = builder.parameterMap.build();
```

How can I fix this problem? I want to make my map immutable but I also want to initialize with required fields as well and that I can only do it in the constructor of `ClientKey` class. And it throws exception while cloning the `ClientKey` object.

Comment: can you clarify where the error message is thrown? It doesn't seem clear from your code above that `ClientKey clonedKey = new ClientKey.Builder(keys).processName("hello").build();` would throw the exception since you don't even have the key `is_clientid`. Where is the next line in your code happening?

Comment: Are you sure this really is an instance of the builder pattern? -- I've never seen someone pass a "builder" to a private constructor just to set the fields of a new object.

Comment: @jamesw1234 exception is thrown at this line `this.parameterMap = builder.parameterMap.build();` but only if I try to clone the `keys`  object into a new one `clonedKey`

Comment: Since at the time of cloning, my `ClientKey` constructor will be called again and then it will try to insert same `is_clientid` again into the map and that's why it throws exception.

Comment: where is `builder` instantiated?

Comment: check this method `build()` in my builder pattern. I guess this error is bcoz you cannot insert same key twice in Guava ImmutableMap?

Comment: your `build()` method doesn't actually instantiate `builder`. In your code `builder.parameterMap.build();` where is `builder` first instantiated

Comment: @jamesw1234 I am not sure what you mean. If you copy paste the whole code and try it out, you should be able to reproduce this very easily.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you construct a `ClientKey`, the `"is_clientid"` key is put in the map. Therefore, if you call your `ClientKey.Builder(ClientKey)` constructor the `putAll` call will copy it to your new `ImmutableMap.Builder` instance. When you then build your cloned `ClientKey`, the `ClientKey` constructor will again try to add the same key to the map, which causes the exception.

The `ImmutableMap.Builder` could have been written in a different way, but it wasn't. If you want to use it, you'll have to live with it.

One solution is to not copy the entry with the `"is_clientid"` key to the new `ImmutableMap.Builder` in the constructor of your `Builder`. Instead of `this.parameterMap = ImmutableMap.<String, String>builder().putAll(key.parameterMap);` you write:

```
this.parameterMap = new ImmutableMap.Builder<>();
for (Map.Entry<String,String> entry : key.parameterMap.entrySet()) {
    if (!"is_clientid".equals(entry.getKey()) {
        this.parameterMap.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
    }
}
```

Another solution is to not use Guava's `ImmutableMap.Builder`, but a normal Java `HashMap` (it does not throw exception when you try to put a duplicate key in it, the old entry is simply overwritten). Then in your `ClientKey` constructor you write:

```
this.parameterMap = Collections.unmodifiableMap(builder.parameterMap);
```

You could also write:

```
this.parameterMap = ImmutableMap.copyOf(builder.parameterMap);
```

but this makes an entire copy of the map, which may take some time for very large maps.

A concluding remark: if all you want to do is copy a `ClientKey`, you do not need a builder; idiomatic Java would use a copy constructor or the `clone()` method (although the latter is discouraged by some).

Comment: Where I should use the first solution you mentioned? Is it also under `ClientKey` constructor or `Builder` constructor?

Comment: @user5447339 I edited the answer. The snippet would come in the constructor of your Builder class.

Comment: "not use Guava's `ImmutableMap`" - the problem is the builder, not the map. If the result should be immutable and key duplicates are to be handled, then it can be built using `ImmutableMap.copyOf(aHashMapUsedAsBuilder)`.

Comment: @maartinus True. I edited the answer. Still, `ImmutableMap.copyOf` makes a copy of the entire map, whereas as `Collections.unmodifiableMap` only creates a view of the original map.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an exception because you're trying to set a value for the key `is_clientid` in the same `ImmutableMap.Builder` used by your single `ClientKey.Builder` class:

```
builder.parameterMap.put("is_clientid", (clientId == 0) ? "false" : "true");
```

As seen in [the documentation](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableMap.Builder.html#put(K,%20V)):

> Associates key with value in the built map. Duplicate keys are not allowed, and will cause `build()` to fail.

Don't re-use the same instance of `ImmutableMap.Builder`.

You can clone an object sort of like this instead:

```
public ClientKey(ClientKey copyee) {
    // Copy fields here
    this.parameterMap = ImmutableMap.copyOf(copyee.parameterMap);
}
```

If you want to use some sort of builder object, you could do something like this:

```
public Builder(ClientKey copyee) {
    this.oldParameterMap = copyee.parameterMap;
}

public ClientKey build() {
    // Create new map here and pass it to new ClientKey somehow
    ImmutableMap.copyOf(oldParameterMap);
    return newKey;
}
```

Comment: Yeah that I was able to figure it out why it throws exception but how to fix it in my case?

Comment: Again, **don't re-use the same instance of `ImmutableMap.Builder`**.

Comment: Can you provide an example of not reusing same instance so that I can understand this?

Comment: I added a small example to help you understand a bit better.

Comment: I used [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16217011/5447339) example which demonstrates how to clone the builder pattern from old to new. In that it was mentioned to pass the old reference in the Builder constructor.

Comment: I still don't understand why you need an additional "builder" class just to copy an object; Do you have a reason or are you just doing it because you saw it there?

Comment: I added an example with some sort of "builder" object.

Comment: Your `new ImmutableMap.Builder().putAll(...).build();` is in no way better than `ImmutableMap.copyOf(oldParameterMap)`.